# Add multiple associations in Sequelize.js

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I understand that Sequelize has a Model function for setting multiple assocations in a hasMany relationship, like `user1.setFollowing()`, as well as a function to add a single assocation, like `user1.addFollowing()`. But the latter does not let you pass an array (I receive an error) - is there any function to let you add multiple associations, like `user1.addFollowings`?

Answer (score 1):

You should use add{ModelName} for add one instance and set{ModelName} for array of instances

```
Project.hasMany(Task)
Task.hasMany(Project)

project.addTask(task1).success(function() {})
```

but

```
project.setTasks([task1, task2]).success(function() {})
```

[example](http://sequelizejs.com/docs/latest/associations#block-5-line-8)

Comment: `setTasks` would replace the entire associations instead of add them. Looking at the code it seems that a `add<Plural>` method exists, that accepts an array of instances, but it doesn't work for me.